# List View - retornando mais de 1 dado em uma linha

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Estou implementando um `app` de notas e tenho que ter uma *list* *view* que deve listar TODAS as “NOTAS” previamente cadastrados, utilizando o método de listagem implementado na DAO;
Cada linha da *ListView* deve apresentar a Data de cadastro da NOTA, Matéria, Bimestre e a Nota.

ou seja como faço pra acrescentar mais de um dado em na linha da *listview*.

Answer (score 2):

Para mostrar mais de uma informação em um item de uma **List View** é necessário criar um **layout** personalizado para os itens da **List View** e um **List Adapter**, que serve para associar as inforamações dos seus objetos aos elementos do seu **layout**.

Ex.: Se tivermos uma lista de objetos (chamaremos de **listaItens**) e quisermos exibir 3 informações de cada objeto dessa lista, devemos criar um primeiramente um **layout_item** com 3 campos (campo1, campo2 e campo3), que poderia ser da seguinte maneira:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_campo1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_campo2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Small Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_campo3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Em seguida, precisamos criar um **List Adapter**, pois é ele quem vai associar as informações de cada informação de um objeto da sua **listaItens** a um elemento do seu **layout_item**. Para isso, criaremos a classe **AdapterItem**:

```java
public class AdapterItem extends BaseAdapter {

    // Lista de itens e contexto da aplicação
    List<SuaClasse> lista;
    Context context;

        public AdapterItemSuaClasse(List<SuaClasse> lista, Context context) {
            this.lista = lista;
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return lista.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {

            return lista.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        // Método responsável por criar o layout de um item da List View e associar as informações de cada item
        // a um elemento do layout
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

                    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                   // cria uma view com o layout  do seu item
                   view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_item, null);

                   // Atribuição normal dos campos de uma view
                    TextView campo1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView_campo1);
                    TextView campo2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView_campo2);
                    TextView campo3 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textview_campo3);

                    campo1.setText(lista.get(position).getCampo1());
                    campo2.setText(lista.get(position).getCampo2());
                    campo3.setText(lista.get(position).getCampo3());

                return view;
        }

    }
```

Após criar o **layout** e o **adapter**, você precisa instanciar o adapter e passar como parametro a sua **listaItens** e o contexto da aplicação. Assim, o adapter automaticamente vai pegar cada item da **listaItens** e associar seus atributos aos campos do layout. Em seguida, devemos dizer para a sua **List View** que você está utilizando um **adapter** para criar os elementos dessa **List View**:

```java
    List View listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listview);

    AdapterItem adapterItem = new AdapterItem(listaItens, context);
    listView.setAdapter(adapterItem);
```